# Shortcut arrows on desktop are different sizes

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons

How can I make the shortcut arrows on my desktop icons consistent? Some are 75% of the image, and others are 20% of the image.

There doesn't seem to be anywhere that this can be edited, or even toggled on/off.

[image: Desktop Icons]